# Modular tabs or long page scroll

Tags: website-design, navigation, users

A content heavy real estate website is deciding whether to switch the navigation to using modular tabs, where content opens in the same pane. Currently, the site uses a long page scroll where all content loads at once and the navigation allows the user to jump to points of content on the page.

Are there any examples of best practices? How should a designer decide which user interface to use?

Here's a link to a sample page:

https://www.thebambergergroup.com/building/17/the-murray-hill-mews+160-east-38th-street/murray-hill/nyc

Screenshots below:

All content loads at once - Active Sales is the first section:

[image]

User can jump to another section, such as amenities:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This tab approach is good, however, if you need more content (new tab) where do you find the space? That is the only issue I can think of.

If you need, get a few users and do a quick user testing on both the designs. That might help a lot.

Comment: A dedicated section for vertical tabs can solve the issue regarding space.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the page length can be reduced if each section was more condensed e.g. updated fonts that aren't so heavy or less padding/spacing between elements, etc.

Check out similar websites for inspiration. Airbnb is a good one because sometimes there's a lot of content but they provide expand/collapse options between sections.

Answer (score 0):

Another consideration here, is how you might want the site to behave when deep linking to content.

With everything in a single page, should I wish to deep link to the section for floor plans - the experience might force the browser to scroll past all the other content elements.

If you go for the tab routing direction, this would negate this 'flash' of content and allow the page to build it's state without needing to worry about displaying other content elements

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the only page option is: how the user returns to the top? Navigation allows the user to jump to the content points on the page, but the "general description" section and the main banner are out.
In this sense the navigation with modular tabs avoids this problem.

Comment: Welcome to UX StackExchange. Kindly go through the site's tour and read about the answering criteria. Your answer does not have enough explanation or reference to be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

One may add as many as content or features to site, but what matters is that the content or features you provided are really needed in the first place or not.
So we can try to reduce that content and then segregation of that content so we can assign a tab to each part.
we can try to reduce scroll as the content we are going to have can be read in a non-sequentially manner rather than sequentially where scrolling is the better solution.

You can try something like [tab example (scroll spy)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/scrollspy/)
just try to keep scroll minimal for each part